# I made an application on my windows computer. Is there any way for me to 'upload/deploy/install' it to just my iPhone and run it on that?

Tags: python, iphone, windows, deployment

The code is a very basic .py file

```
import turtle

turtle.Screen().bgcolor("black")
turtle.color("red")
turtle.begin_fill()

turtle.pensize(3)
turtle.left(50)
turtle.forward(133)
turtle.circle(50, 200)
turtle.right(140)
turtle.circle(50, 200)
turtle.forward(133)

turtle.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

just curious if there is any way for me to upload it to run it on my iPhone. I don't have a mac so I cannot use XCode

Comment: No, at least not easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code right on your iPhone in example in SoloLearn:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sololearn-learn-to-code-apps/id1210079064

Than you can compile it and see result.

Or maybe it's another just for python compilator for iOS